# RESTful service with postman

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs, postman

I'm working on a jax-rs RESTful application and I have a service that is supposed to save a JSON objet into a database through JPA. The service class is something like:

```
@Path("/items")
@Stateless
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ItemsService {

    @Inject
    protected IItemsLogic itemsServiceLogic;

    @POST
    public ItemDTO create(ItemDTO item){
        return itemsServiceLogic.createItem(item);
    }
 }
```

the itemsServiceLogic is just a class that transforms the DTO into another Java class declared as an entity in order to be serialized in a database through JPA.

What happens is that I'm testing the application through the google chrome browser client Postman but when I send a JSON objet into the POST method, the received DTO has no properties so the database doesn't save anything, as all the DTO's properties are null.

I'm using Glassfish 4.0 to host my application and everything with the database works fine. What could be wrong?

The DTO class would be:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class ItemDTO { 
   //Id private 
    Long id; 
   //item's description 
   private String description; 
   //item's name 
   private String name; 

  //Setters and getters
  public Long getId(){
  return id;
 }

  public String getDescription(){
  return description;
 }
  public String getName(){
  return name;
 }

  public void setId(Long nId){
  this.id=nId;
 }

  public void setDescription(String nDescription){
  this.description = nDescription;
 }
  public void setName(String nName){
  this.name=nName;
 }



}
```

And i'm sending the JSON:

```
{"id":1,"description":"some item","name":"item1"}
```

Comment: Can you show the `ItemDTO` class, along with the JSON you're sending.

Comment: The class would be:
`@XmlRootElement
public class ItemDTO {
    
    //Id 
    private Long id;
    
    //item's description
    private String description;
    
    //item's name
    private String name;
}`

And i'm sending the JSON:
`{"id":1,"description":"some item","name":"item1"}`

Comment: Can you edit your post with that information properly formatted, instead of in a comment. Also do you have proper getters and setters for those fields (using correct Javabean naming convention)?

Comment: there it is, sorry for the unreadable comment

Comment: I don't know it works perfectly fine for me. I used all the code you have above, except I just returned the same DTO, and in Postman, selected "raw" and set the header `Content-Type: application/json`.